# TSQL, ensure at least one character appears before @ sign

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql

In TSQL, if I'm searching for valid .com email addresses, I need to make sure there's an @ sign, it ends in .com, and there's at least one character before and after the @.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE [EMAIL] LIKE '%@%.com';"
```

I don't believe the above query would satisfy the requirement of ensuring that there is at least one character before and after the @ sign (and before the .com sign in the second case).  How can I adjust the wildcards in this example to mean "any sequence of 1 or more characters" where each % sign is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [underscore character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) to match a mandatory single character in conjunction with `%` to match optional additional ones.

```
LIKE '_%@_%.com';"
```

Comment: I wish I had any votes left. I'd love a nickel for every time I saw someone forget that `_` exists - not just `%`

Comment: I did forget :) thanks for the quick answer.  I'll accept when the timer checks out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE EMAIL LIKE _%@%_.com;
```

This may satisfy your requirement as _ is used to indicate a compulsory character.

Comment: Select the code and click the `{}` icon to highlight it as code.